# Open core.img in GRUB2

Tags: boot, grub2, mount, source

I have GRUB2 installed to a flash drive. I want to try editing the main.c file to change the header title of GRUB.

How can I mount `core.img`?

The directory is: `/media/youktec/GRUB/boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `main.c` file is a source code file that is compiled (along with other files) into the grub binary.

It's not generally possible to go back from binary files to source files, at least with any accuracy.

You could download the GRUB source code, modify it, then compile and install it. But that's a lot of work.

You could also use a hex editor to find the text you're looking for in the compiled binary and change it, but that is also complex.

Are you sure the option you're looking for isn't available in a config file?

Comment: I don't think you can what I'm trying to do is in the config file. I've done some research but it seems mostly you can only define menu entries. I tried compiling from a source but didn't have much luck recompiling the source. How would one go about using a hex editor? Is it even conventional to use a hex editor?

Comment: Im assuming you are trying to edit the part at the top where it says `GNU GRUB version xxxx` I quickly looked around but I couldn't figure out where it comes from so I can't help with hex editing :( I remember doing something like this with a phone and it was a nightmare just trying to get to the file I needed to edit

Comment: Your assumption is right. Maybe this can't be done the way I wanted to. Thanks for response though. Might look into hex editing, seems interesting.